# C# datagrid problem with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding

```
EditVariationWindowModel edit = (EditVariationWindowModel)this.DataContext;

        var datagrid = dataGrid3;



        foreach (Variation variation in edit.SelQuestion.Variations)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in variation.QuestionParameters)
            {
                var binding = new Binding(parameter.Value);
                var column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                column.Header = parameter.Key.Name;
                column.Binding = binding;
                datagrid.Columns.Add(column);

            }
        }
```

so this is my code in the code behind for my datagrid. I work in wpf.

Now what is the problem: I just get one Row but many duplicate column headers(with the right bindings) but as you will understand already, I don't want them next to eachother but under eachother. for example:

not like this

```
header1 | header2 | header1 | header2|
string1 | string2 | string 1| string2|
```

but

```
 header1 | header2
 string1 | string2
 string1 | string2
```

Anyone knows how I can solve this?

Comment: Does `Variation var in edit.SelQuestion.Variations` even compile? I thought `var` was a reserved word in C#? And even if it is "legal" I wouldn't use it, because it's confusing, I'd rename it `variation`.

Comment: yeah it compiles... but ok, I will change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add first all the columns, and then select them when adding data.

What you're doing is to add a binding with a new column.

EDIT:

What I usually do when I have to Add Rows manually is:

1.- Add DataColumn to DataTable and ColumnStyle to the DataGrid just like:

```
DataColumn fNameColumn8 = new DataColumn();
fNameColumn8.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
m_dataTable.Columns.Add(fNameColumn8);

ColumnStyle myStyleColumn8 = new ColumnStyle(7);
myStyleColumn8.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight;

DataGridTableStyle dataGridTableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
dataGridTableStyle.MappingName = MAPPINGNAME;
dataGridTableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(myStyleColumn8);

this.dataGrid.TableStyles.Add(dataGridTableStyle);
```

2.- Assign mapping name and name to show to ColumnStyles of dataGrid and Columns of DataTable:

```
m_dataTable.Columns[8].ColumnName = this.m_strHeader;

((DataGridTextBoxColumn)this.dataGrid.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles[8]).MappingName = this.m_strHeader;

((DataGridTextBoxColumn)this.dataGrid.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles[8]).HeaderText = this.m_strHeader;
```

3.- Assign the width of the column in the ColumnStyles of the DataGrid:

```
((DataGridTextBoxColumn)this.dataGrid.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles[8]).Width = 20;
```

4.- Fill the rows:

```
DataRow dataRow = this.m_dataTable.NewRow();

dataRow[this.m_strHeader] = "DATA";

this.m_dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

Comment: But how do you do that? I know how to make my columns.. But I don't know how to add a new row foreach questionparameter

Comment: Using DataTable as the DataGrid.DataSource, you can do ((DataTable)dataGrid.DataSource).NewRow() that gives to you a new DataRow that you can Add to the DataSourceDirectly, that's what you have to do.

Comment: and how do I implement this? so first I make my columns? and what do I have to do then?

Comment: I posted an individual example, you have to init each column before of inserting rows.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a column definition for each row... WTF?

Here's a decent tutorial on [How to Bind a DataGrid to a Collection](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection).

Cheers. Keith.

---

**EDIT:**

Try

```
foreach (var parameter in edit.SelQuestion.Variations.First().QuestionParameters)
```

to define your grid columns... see: [First method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx)

Then (as a seperate step) populate the datagrid by iterating through the Variations... or better still **READ** the article linked above, and just bind the grid to the collection. No need to mess-about defining columns, and looping through each row... The grid can do ALL that automatically.

Comment: But here I have the problem that I can't set my ItemsSource, because I need the list questionparameters of each variation... so when i set my itemssource to SelQuestion.Variations, I can't reach my property: Questionparameters of Variation. Or is there a way?